# Why strcpy is defined in Lint_strcpy.c in minix?

Tags: freebsd, minix

For example in FreeBSD strcpy is defined in lib/libc/string/strcpy.c. Why in minix it is defined in lib/libc/string/Lint_strcpy.c, not in strcpy.c just like in FreeBSD? What does Lint prefix mean?

It's worth mentioning that in minix some functions (like strpcpy) are defined in this way. I mean, strpcpy is defined in lib/libc/string/strpcpy.c but strcpy is defined in lib/libc/string/Lint_strcpy.c. What's the point in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually look at the source inside `lib/libc/string/Lint_strcpy.c` you'll find it is an empty definition.

As in the original **NetBSD** source, the actual definition of `strcpy()` used in building the C library for Minix is in `common/lib/libc/string/strcpy.c`.

This is done so that the same definition can be shared directly from the same source file for both the kernel and userland.

The `Lint_` prefix indicates a file which is there just for the purpose of creating a *"lint library"*, and is effectively a shortcut to somewhat simplify the build process for lint libraries (they could/should in theory use the common source file too).